# Check of homework: MIPS instructions that evaluate following expression

Tags: assembly, mips

Assume that the array represented by the variable x is an array of signed integers beginning at address `0x10010000` and put the result of the expression into register `$t0`

```
x[5] + x[8]
```

I want to check how I've done on my answer, or where I've gone wrong? Thanks for any help / feedback.

```
lui  $t1, 0x10010000
ori  $t1, $t1, 0x00010100 
lui  $t2, 0x10010000
ori  $t2, $t2, 0x00001001
add $t0, $t1, $t2
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your code:

- lui does not allow an immediate of that size. You should use either the pseudoinstruction `li  $t1, 0x10010000` or two instructions to form the base address (e.g. a `lui` and an `ori`). `lui` will set the high order 16-bits to the inmediate set in the instruction and the lower 16-bits will be set to zero, and `ori` can be used to set the lower 16-bits. However, in your example the lower 16-bits are zero therefore changing your instruction `lui  $t1, 0x10010000` to `lui  $t1, 0x1001` will do the trick.
- You are not adding the contents but the addresses. You should use `lw` instruction, e.g.: `lw $t2, 20($t1)` to read the fifth element

Comment: yeh the question is to do it without using pseudo instructions, i should have put that in the description. and yes i made a mistake with the offsets, i was trying to put them in as binary values instead of hexadecimal or decimal.

Comment: @Brad: Instead of using `li $t1, 0x10010000` you can use just `lui $t1, 0x1001` which will actually set $t1 to 0x10010000

Comment: @gusbro: Does your last comment take into consideration the endian-ness of the MIPS processor? What I mean is that the default endian-ness is such that 0x1001 is actually sent as 0x10010000 on the address bus?

Comment: @maths-help-seeker: In my previous comment I just stated that immediate 0x10010000 can be loaded to a register by using `lui reg, 0x1001`; endianness deals with memory organization...

Answer (score 0):

1) I think the error is in the second and the fourth statement. The number 0x00010100 is 65792 in decimal. When you are trying to access fifth element in the array, the number should be 20 or 0b00010100 or 0x14. Similarly the fourth statement should 32 or 0x20. This answer assumes that size of integer is 4 bytes.

2) Also, you are just adding the addresses, not the data. You need to change your code to fetch the data from the locations given by the addresses in the $t1 and $t2 registers. Since, it is homework, I would not like to change the code for you.

Comment: yeh i made a mistake with the input of the values, i was trying to put them in as binary instead of binary or hexadecimal. also what do u mean about fetching the data from the locations? i thought the lui and oir instructions loaded the data into the registers, do i need to do a lw and the sw pair? though arent they also pseodo instructions?

Comment: @Brad: `lui` and `ori` are used to store an inmediate (i.e. a constant) in  the register. But your array is stored in memory, therefore you have to use `lw` to get the contents of the array. `lw` and `sw` are **not** pseudoinstructions.

Comment: so would that mean the code would look more like 

`lw $t1, 4097`
`lw $t2, 20 ($t1)`
`lw $t3, 32($t1)`
`add $t0, $t2, $t3`